# iOS - Animate only the 'appendPath' of an UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

there are a lot of examples how to animate along a UIBezierPath. But i can't figure it out, how to animate only the appendPath of an UIBezierPath.

In my case i have the following example:

```
// Create path from view controller
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
                      CGRectMake(0, 0, tutorialController.bounds.size.width,
                                 tutorialController.bounds.size.height) cornerRadius:0];

// Create circle path
UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius];
[path appendPath:circlePath];
[path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

// Create spot layer
spotLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
spotLayer.path = path.CGPath;
spotLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
spotLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
spotLayer.opacity = 0.90;
```

So basically its a circle inside a rect and i now want to animate only the circle. In all attempts the rect was also moved.

Here is my example, how i can animate "along" a path

```
CGPoint pathStart = CGPointMake(96.000000, 226.000000);
CGPoint pathEnd = CGPointMake(120.000000, 300.000000);

[circlePath moveToPoint:pathStart];
[circlePath addLineToPoint:pathEnd];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = circlePath.CGPath;
anim.duration = 5.0;
anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
[spotLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"bezierPathAnim"];
```

But that is not what i want...
What i want to do is, to move my circle path (which is an appended path of a rectangle path) via animation

Does anybody has some ideas?

Regards

Comment: Where exactly is the "animate" part of your code?

Comment: Currently there is nothing that works for me. So i only can animate "along" the paths with a CAKeyframeAnimation.

Comment: Why don't you make two shape layers - one containing a rectangle path and the other containing a circle path - and animate just one of them?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem :-)

Here is the solution...

```
// If there is an old path animate to the new path
if(oldPath != nil){
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    [anim setFromValue:(__bridge id)oldPath];
    [anim setToValue:(__bridge id)[path CGPath]];
    [anim setDuration:0.3];
    [anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [spotLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"path"];
}
```

First of all i kept the oldPath (starting point) and then animate to the new setted path.